# How to achieve TPS at Transaction level not at Request level in BlazeMeter/JMeter

Tags: transactions, jmeter, throughput, blazemeter, tps

> Blockquote

I am executing the tests with Apache JMeter using BlazeMeter PAAS.
I have one requirement, I have multiple transactions in one scenario, and each transaction contains multiple requests, I want to achieve TPS per transaction level. 
Then in this case, Throughput shaping timer, Constant throughput timer, Limit RPS(BlazeMeter) are not working. Even I tried with yaml configuration also, but that also didnt work.
Could you please tell me how can I achieve it through yaml if possible.

EX: 
If no of Tx's in scenario = 3
TPS targeted per Tx = 20
I need to achieve each transaction controller to achieve 20 TPS and the total scenario TPS will be 60.

Please suggest me how can I do this with yaml config.

Taurus Configuration in YAML:
modules:
  jmeter:
    properties:
      httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources: true
execution:
- concurrency: 50
  hold-for: 5m
  ramp-up: 1m
  throughput:60
  steps: 3
  scenario: Thread Group

scenarios:
  Thread Group:
    retrieve-resources: false
    script: Blazedemo.jmx

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) to your Test Plan and tick `Generate parent sample` box

   [image]
2. Put your Samplers under the Transaction controller (as children)
3. Add [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) to your Test Plan and configure it as follows:

   [image: JMeter Precise Throughput Timer]

In this setup you will have 60 transactions per minute, each of them will contain 3 requests.